# protecting a json endpoint in django as part of an ajax call

Tags: python, django

I have a conceptual question.

I am currently using an ajax call to send data from my database to the django template to populate a chart on the page

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('chartdata1/', tracker.get_chart_data_json1, name="global_trend_chart"), 
]
```

views.py

```
def get_chart_data_json1(request):
    data = {}
    cd = ChartData.get_global_trend()
    data['chart_data'] = cd
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data, default=str), content_type='application/json')
```

HTML / JAVASCRIPT

```
var chartDataUrl = "{% url 'global_trend_chart' %}"   
$.getJSON(chartDataUrl,
        function(data) {
            chartOptions.xAxis.categories = data['chart_data']['date'];
            chartOptions.series[0].data = data['chart_data']['confirmedcases'];
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartOptions);
    })
```

While this is working fine, I don’t want people to be able to access the url directly (i.e. I don’t want them to be able to access the json data by going to myurl.com/chartdata1). I just want this view/data to be accessible by my django template to populate the charts there. I also don’t require users to login to see the main page so don’t want to create a @login_required restriction to the view

Is there any way for me to protect the myurl.com/chartdata1 endpoint so it’s only consumable by the charts?

Thanks

Comment: No, this is not possible and doesn't make sense. You're actually not sending the data to your django template, you're sending it to your browser. Open your browser developer tools and look at the Network tab. Anyone can do that and view the chart data returned anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass some extra data in the GET request and then in your view you can check for that extra data. If there is no extra data in the view, you can return a `ForbiddenResponse`. Obviously anyone can just look at your JavaScript code and find it, **so this is in no way secure** but this will prevent people from being able to just target the url.

If your data is sensitive then you should think about setting up token authentication. Have a look at the authentication in [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

Hay,
in this case instead of rendering actual content in JSON you can render content as a HTML. And then using Ajax you can show that in a template. if you understand the way i have shown in example it will be cool.

## view example.

```
def load_graph_html(request):
    data = dict()
    context = {
      #some context data
     }

    data['graph_html'] = render_to_string('graph.html', context, request=request)

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

you will pass your json dict in context then in "graph.html" you will write code for graph then pass it to json. so, people can't she that JSON it will be html content in a JSON.

## Ajax example

```
$.ajax({
      "url": url,
      "dataType": "json",
      "type": "GET",
      "success": function (data) {
        $("#rigadmin_order_form_loaded_area").html(data.graph_html)
      }
});
```

it maybe help you to hide json